# Pythonic method of chaining custom functions across a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, shapefile

I've been googling this for a while and cannot come up with a satisfying answer that I understand how to implement.  I'm a Python novice and I'm trying to figure out a Pythonic way of chaining together a few functions within a function.

My function is simply to convert a shape file into a tool agnostic format that can be used for mapping.

The function works as intended, it just seems really inelegant, creating functions and then applying functions one by one, but as mentioned, I cant find a slicker way of doing this...

```
import re
import pandas as pd

def shape_to_string(shp_in):
    # convert geoseries to list of strings
    shp_in = list(shp_in.astype(str))

    # function to strip out numeric, brackets and leading/trailing spaces
    strip_chars = lambda x: re.sub('[aA-zZ()]','', x).lstrip().rstrip()
    # function to split on space
    split_string = lambda x: x.split(' ')

    # apply function over incoming list
    clean_shp = list(map(strip_chars, shp_in))
    split_shp = list(map(split_string, clean_shp))

    # format as dataframe
    cols = ['long', 'lat']
    shp_out = pd.DataFrame(split_shp, columns=cols)

    return(shp_out)
```

example data:

```
0     POINT (540409.1130999997 185311.6275999993)
1     POINT (541906.0785999997 185683.2414999995)
2     POINT (543515.8586999997 186487.3535999991)
3     POINT (545384.0466999998 187089.3987000007)
4     POINT (546470.5884999996 187325.4045000002)
```

Comment: Well, for starters you can simplify your two functions to `lambda x: re.sub('[aA-zZ()]','', x).strip().split(' ')`. And you can just pass that `lambda` expression to `map` directly (otherwise there's no point to using a lambda, and you should just use a normal function definition tobegin with). But what's the point of defining these functions inside your `shape_to_string`? Just defined them once outside.